# Advanced forum - Customize comment links alone

Tags: theming, nodes

I am using advanced forum module. I want to customize the link in comments like **reply, edit, delete**.

I know I can use theme_links function, but it is affecting all places where `$content['links']` is used.

I also used something like function `mytheme_links__comment__node_forum($variables)` but is not working too.

Any suggestion on how I can customize the html for link generated under forum comments alone?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *do* with them?

Comment: I just want to remove ul and li tag and use div instead